# Use vagrant for Phundament development

Tags: php, yii2, phundament

A little bit about our workflow. Our developer machines use Windows as OS, also our projects(usually lamp or lemp stack, sometimes postgres instead of mysql) on git lab server have vagrant file for full envirenment description. Now we decided to try Phundament. **So what's correct workflow should be?** Should we install docker on windows or use any vagrant box with phundament and its docker running images inside this box? I think second way is unnecessary level of abstraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Full disclosure: I am the author of Phundament.*

We recommend a Docker-based workflow. 
But it depends on your needs which way you choose.

AFAIK Windows is planning Docker-support natively. We, for example, were using Vagrant in the beginning, but switched now to `docker-machine` since it has become much more stable.

So basically Phundament should run with pure PHP on Vagrant or on docker-machine...